# Laravel Spatie middleware using role OR permission

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

I am using **Laravel Spatie** package and I have inserted all the permissions that I want and an Admin Role.

> What I am trying to do:

I am trying to check in each route whether user is an ***admin (can do ANYTHING)*** or not an admin and has a certain permission.

> What I have tried:

I have tried to add `|` sign.

```
// GET ALL SEASONS
Route::get('/', 'SeasonsController@index')
            -> name('index')
            -> middleware(['role:admin|permission:seasons show active']);
```

> What happened VS expected behavior:

Whenever I log in with a user that has `seasons show active` permission I get `403 Forbidden`.

But if I removed `role:admin` the user get the permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's preferrable to work with permissions only.

Grant all the permission to your role admin (seasons show active ... and others). 
Then you will not need role:admin in your middleware.

To grant all permissions on your role admin code like below should do the job

```
$permissions = \Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission::all()

$role = \Spatie\Permission\Models\Role::where('name', 'admin')->first();

// foreach on permissions
 $role->givePermissionTo($permission);
// end foreach
```

Comment: Yes I have read about that and that what I was thinking about.
Is there a way so I could assign all permissions to a certain user? I mean a Spatie Function

Comment: `$permissions = \Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission::all()

$role = \Spatie\Permission\Models\Role::where('name', 'admin')->first();

// foreach on permissions
 $role->givePermissionTo($permission);
// end foreach 
`
should do the job

Comment: Please edit the answer so I could accept it to help others

Answer (score 0):

you can work with both role and permission by applying on middleware

```
    //
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['permission:publish articles|edit articles']], function () {
    //
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['role_or_permission:super-admin|edit articles']], function () {
```

You can protect your controllers similarly, by setting desired middleware in the constructor:

````
{
    $this->middleware(['role:super-admin','permission:publish articles|edit articles']);
}```
````